# Android get text EditText to AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have to take the text from an AlertDialog.

For the AlertDialog I use a specific layout: `custom_alertdialog`

Instead for all the project use: `another layout`

I tried like this:

```
View layout = getLayoutInflater().Inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog,null);
```

Or so:

```
View layout = View.inflate(SimpleVideoStream.this, R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
```

But the text is not taken in either case.
How can I do?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimpleVideoStream.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Subtitle");
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setPositiveButton(
                "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
                        final View layout = View.inflate(SimpleVideoStream.this, R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);

                        EditText url_ele = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.url);
                        String sub = url_ele.getText().toString();
                        Log.v("Ok:","/"+sub);
                        if (!sub.equals("")) {
                            showSub = !showSub;
                            Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
                                    null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null, Format.OFFSET_SAMPLE_RELATIVE);
                            MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(sub), textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);

                            videoSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);
                            player.prepare(videoSource, false, false);
                        }
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton(
                "Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
        alert.setView(dialoglayout);
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `builder` instance, you inflated a layout( layout **A**). Before `setView()` method, you inflated another layout(layout **B**). These two layout are different.

You could do like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimpleVideoStream.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null); 
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null))
final EditText editText = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.url); 

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     //Do something
                    }
                }
            });
       .setNegativeButton(){
                   //Do something
       };
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you inflate a View, it doesn't share an instance with any other times you've inflated it. So what you passed to `setView()` is completely different from what you're calling `findViewById()` on. You need to create only one instance and then reference that.

For example:

```
View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);

EditText text1 = view1.findViewById(R.id.some_edittext);
EditText text2 = view2.findViewById(R.id.some_edittext);

text1.setText("Hello");

String text2text = text2.getText().toString(); //this will be null, because text1 and text2 aren't the same instance, because view1 and view2 aren't the same instance.
```

Move

```
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
```

above where you set the positive button, and make it final:

```
final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
builder.setPositiveButton(...
```

Remove both `inflatedView` and `layout` from inside your listener, and use `dialogLayout`:

```
EditText url_ele = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.url);
```

Comment: I did this: final View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);

builder.setPositiveButton(.... 


But it does not seem to work.

Comment: Don't literally copy what I put. I just showed you where to put that line by showing part of what should be below it. __NEVER__ copy and paste code without reading it!